# What do I have to do to make SSL work here?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

Brand new Ubuntu 18.04 installation on a virtual server.
Did a lamp install following a tutorial on digitalocean. Everything worked out fine.
Then I encountered a problem when trying to get SSL to work.
Everytime I turn "SSLEngine on" in the conf file (apache2).. the webserver cannot start anymore:

> apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

I did journalctl -xe which told me:

> Sep 25 22:49:42 localhost sshd[13272]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
>
> Sep 25 22:49:44 localhost sshd[13272]: Failed password for invalid user 13.244.151.230 from 168.63.16.141 port 50264 ssh2
>
> Sep 25 22:49:46 localhost sshd[13272]: Received disconnect from 168.63.16.141 port 50264:11: Client disconnecting normally [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:49:46 localhost sshd[13272]: Disconnected from invalid user 13.244.151.230 168.63.16.141 port 50264 [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: Invalid user webapp from 49.231.238.162 port 43604
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=49.2>
>
> Sep 25 22:50:24 localhost sshd[13274]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 119.45.21.98 port 33268 [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: Invalid user webapp from 49.231.238.162 port 43604
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
>
> Sep 25 22:50:30 localhost sshd[13276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=49.231.238.162
>
> Sep 25 22:50:32 localhost sshd[13278]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=167.71.3.137  user=root
>
> Sep 25 22:50:33 localhost sshd[13276]: Failed password for invalid user webapp from 49.231.238.162 port 43604 ssh2
>
> Sep 25 22:50:33 localhost sshd[13280]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=185.244.39.159  user=root
>
> Sep 25 22:50:34 localhost sshd[13276]: Received disconnect from 49.231.238.162 port 43604:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:34 localhost sshd[13276]: Disconnected from invalid user webapp 49.231.238.162 port 43604 [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:34 localhost sshd[13278]: Failed password for root from 167.71.3.137 port 36944 ssh2
>
> Sep 25 22:50:34 localhost sshd[13280]: Failed password for root from 185.244.39.159 port 60282 ssh2
>
> Sep 25 22:50:35 localhost sshd[13278]: Received disconnect from 167.71.3.137 port 36944:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:35 localhost sshd[13278]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 167.71.3.137 port 36944 [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:36 localhost sshd[13280]: Received disconnect from 185.244.39.159 port 60282:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
>
> Sep 25 22:50:36 localhost sshd[13280]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 185.244.39.159 port 60282 [preauth]

I don't really know what to make of this.
I tried starting over, wiped everything and installed again, but same result...
I really hope someone can point me in the right direction.. I've been sitting here for hours..
Thanks in Advance!

PS: I hope I didn't fail any formating rules here..

Comment: Let me guess, you used https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04.  It looks ok and seem to cover it all.  Put `LogLevel debug` in your httpd configuration, try again, and consult your error_log.  It will show you Apache messages.  `journalctl` will show you a lot of stuff that might not even be related to httpd.  Here you have sshd errors.  Does not help with Apache.  You might have a syntax issue in your configs, or permissions issues, ...  error_log are critical here to help!

Comment: As an aside, being new to SO, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].  Asking a good question is often 90% of solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I will take the tour before the next question!

I did not take that tutorial. It's a wildcard ssl certificate, not self-signed. 

The error log gave me the following output:
"[Fri Sep 25 22:48:53.573921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12138] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 25 22:48:53.674161 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 13256] AH02565: Certificate and private key lift-me-up.com:443:0 from /etc/ssl/private/certificate.cer and /etc/ssl/private/privatekey.key do not match"

I got the certificates and the key from the IONOS website directly. What to do? :(

Comment: hum, redownload the files to ensure you have a perfect match.  Worst case, contact 1&1 support.